# How to get output of a running script before it's done executing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I'm trying to make a basic panel on which I can manage my Minecraft servers. To do that I need to run a shell script and copy its output while it's still running. From what I've seen in the docs for `Popen` all read methods wait for the process to finish before returning any output. This is the code I'm trying with right now. Is there any way to start a process in the background and copy its output before the process has terminated?

```py
shell = subprocess.Popen("./start.sh", shell= True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

def getconsole() -> str:
    stdout = shell.communicate(timeout=1)[0]
    string = stdout.decode("utf-8")
    return string
```

Comment: Maybe consider `pexpect`? https://pypi.org/project/pexpect/

Comment: This should be exactly like what you need > https://stackoverflow.com/a/17698359/12128167